# Pinescript Renko based chart exiting on bar open working fine but bar close based exit are not working

Tags: pine-script

I have written an algorithm in pinescript for trading with process orders onbar close setting as true. I am using renko charts with 20 pips brick size. I am also using 20 pips stop-loss. If during a stop-loss the exit happens on the open of bar then the following martingale based Position code is executed properly but if the stop-loss exit happens on the close of bar then further martingale based postion sizing is not working. Why the bar open based trades are working ok and bar closed based trades are not working as intended.

Everything on chat gpt to ensure that every stop-loss is treated same way i.e. bar open based and close based

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Did you mean to include some code in your question?